# Binding events with Javascript, changing id of elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this code:

```
$("#container").on("click","#button1",action1);

$("#container").on("click","#button2",action2);

function action1(){
    // do something
    // change button1 id to button2
    $("#button1").prop("id","button2");
}

function action2(){
    // do something
}
```

So when I click on button1, the action1 will change the button1 to button2.
 But the problem is after changing the id, the event action2 (which only must be executed when clicking #button2) is being executed

Comment: Well, using your posted code, action2 is **not** getting automatically invoked: http://jsfiddle.net/7r3baogx/

Comment: What is the question ? what you looking for ? what you expect from your code to do ?

Comment: @techfoobar: Yes it is -- just click the button a second time.

Comment: What is expected `id` of initial `#button2` ? Existing `js` would create duplicate `id`s of `#button2` ?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder - But that is what is expected. right? Unlike state in the post, it isn't getting executed right after the id gets changed.

Comment: @techfoobar: It's the bit at the end that makes the question clear (to me): *"But the problem is after changing the id, the event action2 (which only must be executed when clicking #button2) is being executed"* E.g., they want to change the ID, but *not* have the handler that gets called change. I don't think they mean it gets run immediately when the `id` is changed, just that subsequent clicks cause that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But the problem is after changing the id, the event action2 (which only must be executed when clicking #button2) is being executed

The reason is that you haven't hooked the handler to the button element, you've hooked it to the *container*, and then told jQuery that *when the event happens*, it should check to see if the event travelled through an element that matches the `#button1` selector during the bubbling process. When you change button1's `id` to `button2`, it doesn't match anymore — but it does match the *other* handler, so the other handler gets called. This dynamic nature of the dispatching is what makes event delegation so useful.

You can "fix" this by

1. Not changing the `id`, which is an unusual thing to do.
2. Hooking the handler *directly* rather than using event delegation. Of course, if you have a reason for using delegation, this isn't a good option. :-)
3. Using something else, like a class, to identify the buttons in the delegated `on` calls.

**Note**, however, that `id` values **must** be unique. So if you're going to change the `id` of `button1`, you can't change it to `button2` — that `id` is already in use. In the examples below, I've used `newbutton1` instead.

Example of #2 (in case you didn't really need delegation):

```js
$("#button1").on("click",action1);

$("#button2").on("click",action2);

function action1(){
    // do something
    alert("action1, the id of the button is: " + this.id);
    // change button1 id to newbutton1
    $("#button1").prop("id","newbutton1");
}

function action2(){
    // do something
    alert("action2, the id of the button is: " + this.id);
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <input type="button" id="button1" value="button1">
  <input type="button" id="button2" value="button2">
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Example of #3:

```js
$("#container").on("click", ".first-button", action1);

$("#container").on("click", ".second-button", action2);

function action1(){
    // do something
    alert("action1, the id of the button is: " + this.id);
    // change button1 id to newbutton1
    $("#button1").prop("id","newbutton1");
}

function action2(){
    // do something
    alert("action2, the id of the button is: " + this.id);
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <input type="button" id="button1" class="first-button" value="button1">
  <input type="button" id="button2" class="second-button" value="button2">
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```